# Net Core 2 Console App - DI 'Unable to resolve service for type...'

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, console-application

I've been reading several posts but nothing seems to fit to my problem.

I'm developing a console app with .Net Core 2.1 and EF Core trying to follow Microsoft's advices but I'm facing with the next problem.

I've a project named *myproject.data* which contains all the interfaces and services. This one, for example

**ILeagueService.cs**

```
public interface ILeaguesService
{
    List<Leagues> GetAllLeaguesValids();
}
```

**LeagueService.cs**

```
private statsContext _context;

public LeaguesService(statsContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public List<Leagues> GetAllLeaguesValids()
{
    return _context.Leagues.Where(x => (x.DateFirstMatch != null || x.CurrentLastSeason == true) && x.Active == true).OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();
}
```

Then, I have all the methods of my app separated and all of them inherit from the same class. In this Base.cs class I setup the *ServiceProvider*

**Base.cs**

```
public ServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

public Base()
{
    ConfigureServices();

    _config = new HelperConfig(CONFIG_FILE);
    _html = GetHelperHtml();
    _context = GetContext();
}

private void ConfigureServices()
{
    _serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddScoped<ILeaguesService, LeaguesService>()
        .BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

When I try to use the LeagueService in one of the methods I get the 'Unable to resolve service for type myproject.stats.statsContext' error

**GetNextMatches.cs**

```
private ILeaguesService _leagueService;

public GetNextMatches()
{
   _config.GetSection(AppsettingsModel.BetExplorerUrlsSection).Bind(betExplorerSectionKeys);

    _leagueService = _serviceProvider.GetService<ILeaguesService>(); <-- In this line I get the error
}
```

Comment: Why not use a traditional Startup.cs?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but AFAIK a console app doesn't have Startup.cs

Comment: @RafaelOsunaDominguez `Startup.cs` is just a file to place the various `Configure` methods. Your code splits that configuration between `Base.cs` and `GetNextMatches.cs` so it's hard to understand which part does what. `GetNextMatches` *shouldn't* try to access the DI and configuration itself, its constructor should receive whatever is needed as a parameter. The class itself should be created using DI

Comment: @RafaelOsunaDominguez where did `GetNextMatches` find `_serviceProvider` and `_config` anyway? Those are defined in `Base.cs`. Does it *inherit* from `Base`? In this case it breaks the DI/Configuration model completely. You end up with a *different* DI and Configuration container per *object*

Comment: Won't you need to register a concrete for statsContext so that the DI container can push it into the ctor for LeagueService? At least, I think that's what the error is saying.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok, so I understand that I can create the file and use it as usual I do in a Web project. In that case there's no need, as you say, to put all the code in Base.cs and GetNextMatches. Do you have any example? TY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `ServiceProvider` DI you have to register all of the classes in the hierarchy. The DI container is trying to create your `LeagueService` class but to call its constructor it needs to create an instance of `statsContext`. However it cannot find that in its registry so it throws the exception.

The solution is to add `statsContext` to your services collection.

```
private void ConfigureServices()
{
    _serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddScoped<ILeaguesService, LeaguesService>()
        .AddScoped<statsContext>()
        .BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

I am going to assume your `_context` variable is the `statsContext` you want to inject so you can use your `GetContext()` method to create the context for you:

```
private void ConfigureServices()
{
    _serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddScoped<ILeaguesService, LeaguesService>()
        .AddSingleton<statsContext>(GetContext())
        .BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

This will call your `GetContext()` once to create your single instance of `statsContext`. Now, whenever you call

```
_leagueService = _serviceProvider.GetService<ILeaguesService>();
```

DI will inject the singleton instance of `statsContext` when it creates your `LeageService` class.

Comment: Works perfect but, as a result of @PanagiotisKanavos' comments, I have doubts about whether this is a correct design of the application.

So, I've a Base.cs class that I use to share and setup DI and other elements in the classes that really do the tasks